# iCloud Drive to behave like Dropbox

Tags: dropbox, icloud

In my Dropbox, I have files inside a number of custom-made folders. I am able to view these files and folders inside apps that support Dropbox on my iPhone.

I want iCloud Drive to behave in the same way therefore files arranged in custom-made folders that visible from inside any apps that support iCloud Drive on my iPhone. However it appears that to view files in iCloud Drive from an app on my iPhone, the files need to stored inside the folder for that specific iPhone app.

How can I set up iCloud Drive like Dropbox?

Answer (score 1):

There are apps in the iOS app store that will allow viewing and editing of the files stored in your iCloud Drive account, I use Documents, by Readdle, for this on my iPhone 5s. Documents allows you to manage iCloud Drive files, including downloading and uploading of files. Keep in mind that a desktop Mac includes a file manager, whereas iOS is set up differently and doesn't include the same functionality.

Comment: Thanks but that. The reason I want to use iCloud Drive is to avoid manually downloading and uploading files. I want to be able to edit a file on my iPhone then forget about, safe in the knowledge that it will appear in Finder on my Mac. Dropbox currently requires a manual download/upload step which I want to get rid of.

Comment: You can edit files within some of the third-party apps, such as Documents. The only drawback to Documents is that you must first download the file, edit it and upload the revision. Other than that, the only way to edit a file is to use the app that is assigned for the file type of the desired file, that's the way iOS operates (app-based rather than file-based).

Comment: Numbers for iOS almost does what I want. I edit a file on my iPhone, forget about it and it appears in iCloud Drive on my Mac. The only problem is it appears files need to be inside the Numbers folder in iCloud Drive

Comment: Yes, as I stated earlier, that is how iOS works. A file must be inside the folder for the app that is assigned to cover that particular file type - in this case, a .numbers file. You can move a .numbers file to a different folder, but you'll have to do so manually.

Comment: But I mean that the .numbers file must be inside the Numbers folder in iCloud Drive on my Mac, which massively reduces the effectiveness of iCloud,

Comment: I'm wondering if it would benefit you to unlearn old file management habits and adopt habits that are more iOS/OS X-centric. I was in the same boat a few months ago, when I switched from another system to OS X, and have found that changing my habits resolved a number of problems. Just an idea.